Laptop screen flickers when I put my mouse pointer in some certain points on the screen, but this doesnt occur when I am in the BIOS [PROBLEM FIXED]
I first thought it was a hardware issue, but then why does it only happen when I put my pointer in a certain point only and not happen when I am in the BIOS? I also reinstalled Ubuntu thinking maybe drivers were faulty, still the problem persist. I am really clueless as what maybe causing this.
Below I give a screenshot of the position of the pointer that causes this problem.

The screen can update usually without flickering as I have tested playing many videos. It only happens when I put my mouse pointer at that particular position. Also it only happens if I keep my mouse pointer stationary at that point. Moving the pointer through that position doesn't cause flickering.
My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 24.04 and these are my hardware config.

EDIT
I fixed the problem by changing my resolution from 1366x768 to 1280x720. If i revert back to 1366x768 resolution the problem again reappears. Maybe it has something to do with some conflict between native display resolution and resolution set in the os. But I am not that tech savy so I can't test it further. But I am still curious why it occurred and why only at at certain points on the screen. If anyone can share any info it will be great.
Also, thanks to everyone who suggested me what to do.

Sorry, I have edited to include my ubuntu release details. This problem also occurred when I was using 22 LTS release before reinstalling 24 LTS

If this can be reproduced in the "Try Ubuntu" environment of a LiveUSB, then please file a bug report with details about how to reproduce in that environment and your hardware information. AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker, and problems reported to AskUbuntu won't be forwarded.

If the issue cannot be reproduced in the "Try Ubuntu" environment, then some more troubleshooting is needed.

Are you calling the system details the BIOS?

Thanks everyone for your help. I fixed the problem by changing my resolution from 1366x768 to 1280x720. If i revert back to 1366x768 resolution the problem again reappears.
